# What does 'include and 'define means? and what do they do?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm new in system Verilog, and I'm going through a .svh file. In he script there are lines that states the use of 'include and 'define and sometimes even 'ifndef, for example:

> 'include CHECK_A

and also

> 'define CHECK_B

What does the apostrophe means? and what does each of them do?

Comment: These would be basic verilog directives if you use correct syntax (which you did not). You need to go through a verilog tutorial first. Also note, verilog is not a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

These are compiler directives and all explained in section 22 of the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM. Compiler directives control what source text is fed into the compiler.